# When installing a package with NPM, can you tell it to use a different version of one of its dependencies?

Tags: node.js, dependencies, npm

Say you want to install a library `lib-a` which has dependencies `dep-1` and `dep-2`. If `lib-a` has declared in its package.json to use a version of `dep-2` that is out of date (say it doesn't work on node 0.8.0 which just came out), but there is a branch of `dep-2` that works with node 0.8.0 - branch name `node0.8.0`.

So the packages in the equation are:

```
git://github.com/user-a/lib-a
git://github.com/user-b/dep-1
git://github.com/user-c/dep-2
git://github.com/user-c/dep-2#node0.8.0
```

Is there a way to tell NPM to install `lib-a`, but use `dep-2#node0.8.0` instead of `dep-2`?

With NPM you can install a specific branch of a project like this:

```
npm install git://github.com/user-c/dep-2#node0.8.0
```

And if I were to customize the package.json of `lib-a`, you could tell it to use `dep-2#node0.8.0` like this:

```
{
  "name": "lib-a",
  "dependencies": {
    "dep-1": ">= 1.5.0",
    "dep-2": "git://github.com/user-c/dep-2#node0.8.0"
  }
}
```

By modifying the package.json you can then run

```
npm install lib-a
```

and it will install the node 0.8.0 compatible `dep-2` branch. But, that requires I have access to modifying `lib-a`, which for my specific case I don't. Technically, I could fork `lib-a` and make the above change to package.json. But in my specific case, `lib-a` is a dependency of *another* library, so I'd have to fork the project it's referenced in, and on and on...

So the question is, is there a way to tell NPM to install `lib-a`, and tell it to use the `node0.8.0` branch of `dep-2`? Something like this:

```
npm install lib-a --overrides dep-2:git://github.com/user-c/dep-2#node0.8.0
```

That would be awesome. If it's not possible, that would be good to know so I can prepare myself to have to fork/customize the chain of projects.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**NPM install syntax:**

```
npm install (with no args in a package dir)
npm install <tarball file>
npm install <tarball url>
npm install <folder>
npm install [@<scope>/]<name> [--save|--save-dev|--save-optional] [--save-exact]
npm install [@<scope>/]<name>@<tag>
npm install [@<scope>/]<name>@<version>
npm install [@<scope>/]<name>@<version range>
npm i (with any of the previous argument usage)
```

so you can choose one of these methods to install your modules.

The case of the simplest way to install a specific version is this one:

```
npm install module@0.0.2
```

more info:
https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Comment: It looks like if you install the dependency first, then the other libraries that require that dependency won't download their own. That solves the problem! Thanks!

Comment: Is that correct? I tried npm -g install /path/to/my/fork-with-fix and then npm -g install package-which-should-use-forked-dependency-with-fix and ... it still downloads official version.

Comment: Have a look at `npm link`.

Comment: Yeah, this answer really doesn't answer the question as I understand it at all. Lance Pollard's comment above seems to be the answer but I'm not sure under what circumstances I should be able to count on that behaviour. c.f. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806152/how-do-i-override-nested-npm-dependency-versions which discusses `npm shrinkwrap` as another potential solution

Comment: Looks like the behaviour @LancePollard's discovered in his comment is documented by https://npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-install.html#ALGORITHM — if an alternate (but still "satisfying") dependency is already installed "further up the tree" as it were, then the buggy one will mercifully NOT get installed as a sub-submodule.

Comment: @LancePollard has the right idea, but doesn't explain it fully.

As an example, I was trying to install underscore-cli. It is broken OOTB because the version of commander is newer. Specifying which version of commander to use was accomplished with: npm install -g commander@1.0.5 underscore-cli.

Using Maciej Łopaciński's example: npm -g install /path/to/my/fork-with-fix package-which-should-use-forked-dependency-with-fix should probably work.

Comment: I was trying `npm install module 0.0.2` since morning. You saved my day. +1.

Comment: Updated link to npm install algorithm: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install#algorithm