# NPM installs two version of jQuery which I don't want

Tags: jquery, npm

I'm using jquery v 3.*
One of module has jquery depency with v 2.* and which is installed.
But I don't want to.
I'm using webpack and typescript so I have jQuery version conflicts.
Can I tell npm to use jQuery 3.* instead of installing jQuery 2.* ?

Edit: All available versions of module have depency on jQuery 2.* so I cannot use different version of module.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When installing a package with NPM, can you tell it to use a different version of one of its dependencies?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233133/when-installing-a-package-with-npm-can-you-tell-it-to-use-a-different-version-o)

Comment: It's not the same - All available versions of plugin depends on jQuery 2.*