# How to install beta version via npm

Tags: npm, npm-install

I need to install a *beta* version `3.0.0` of [react-docgen](https://github.com/reactjs/react-docgen).

Is it possible to install a *beta* version via npm?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When installing a package with NPM, can you tell it to use a different version of one of its dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11233133/when-installing-a-package-with-npm-can-you-tell-it-to-use-a-different-version-o)

Answer (score 14):

Yes, it's possible to install a beta version using the `@` symbol. For example to install [react-docgen](https://github.com/reactjs/react-docgen/tree/v3.0.0-beta7) *(v3.0.0-beta7)* run the following command:

`npm install -g react-docgen@3.0.0-beta7`

Further information about installing specific versions can be found in the [npm-install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) documentation.

Answer (score 12):

The syntax for [`npm install`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) includes both of the following overloads:

```sh
npm install [<@scope>/]<name>@<tag>
npm install [<@scope>/]<name>@<version>
```

For tag, you can specify either `@latest` and `@beta` like this:

```sh
npm install @11ty/eleventy@latest  # latest stable release
npm install @11ty/eleventy@beta    # latest beta release
```

Interestingly, if you don't specify a tag, the default, set by your [npm config](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#tag), is `@latest`

You can also find out which versions are available by running [`npm view`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view.html)

```sh
npm view @11ty/eleventy
```

[image: npm view]

Answer (score 6):

**To install a *specific*** `beta` **version**:

```
npm install -g react-docgen@3.0.0-beta7
//or
yarn global add react-docgen@3.0.0-beta7  // if you use yarn
```

---

**P.S.:**

In order to see all versions of a package (including alpha, beta , pre-release, release):

`npm show <package> versions --json`

**Example:**

`npm show react-docgen versions --json`

[image]

---

You can also install a certain version using a `tag`!

```
npm install <name>@<tag>
```

In order to see which `tag`s are available for this package, you have to run:

`npm view react-docgen`

[image]

A `tag` can be used when installing packages as a reference to a version
instead of using a specific version number (alias)

Comment: Commonly ```@next``` is NOT alias for latest beta and ```@latest``` is NOT alias for latest stable version for any arbitrary package. 
Real version aliases of a package can only be known via ```npm view <package>```

Comment: You are right. In this case the distributor uses the "next" tag for the latest `alpha` version of the `react-docgen` package. I will edit my answer to make it more clear. Thank you.